# SQLException errno:150 during gradle build

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, mariadb

So i'm building a spring boot based API and upon building the project while connected to the mariaDB server thats hosting the DB, im getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table pow2image add constraint FKfnn5r6ascraodeblk9mrkedfq foreign key (image_id) references Image (id)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table 'praze.#sql-db9_175' (errno: 150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2607)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1480)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
    ... 81 more
```

These are the create scripts for the tables involved

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pow2image;    
    CREATE TABLE `pow2image` (
          `pow_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`pow_id`,`image_id`),
          CONSTRAINT `FKd134yk996sx2f8a9e4as75cyd` FOREIGN KEY (`pow_id`) REFERENCES `place_of_worship` (`id`),
          CONSTRAINT `FKsk2761pm5gcx9dd09gnww1ord` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `image` (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS place_of_worship;
        CREATE TABLE place_of_worship (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(240) DEFAULT NULL,
            address VARCHAR(240) DEFAULT NULL,
            phone VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
            google_id VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
            description VARCHAR(300)
        )  ENGINE=INNODB;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS image;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            server_location VARCHAR(255),
            path_to_image VARCHAR(255),
            upload_date DATETIME
        )  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Though when i build the project while connected to my locally hosted MySQL server, the project builds without error.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| constraint_name             | table_name         |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| FK3ibpw0h9kwvc50b4i1jh8dl   | users2profileimage |
| FK3ibpw0h9kwvc50b4i1jhwv8dl | users2review       |
| FKhqe0if0vbqn7j3hd32bc1gkhi | users2review       |
| FKhqe0if0vbqn7j3hd32bkhi    | users2profileimage |
| FKo68tp3gfehrsjesas3eltvk9w | pow2review         |
| FKrd83cby4x2n561nx477y46kk8 | pow2review         |
| religion_ibfk_1             | religion           |
| review_ibfk_1               | review             |
| review_ibfk_2               | review             |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

i queried all of the foreign keys in the DB and it looks as though i'm getting and error for a key that doesn't even exist?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that it is not possible to create FOREIGN for the table 'pow2image', as there is something wrong with your referances.